# Squid Proxy Server help

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

I followed the guide at http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/SquidProxyServer and I am trying to set up a Squid proxy server, but I get the follow error when I try and connect through the proxy:

```
    ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved

While trying to retrieve the URL: http://google.com

The following error was encountered:

    Access Denied.

    Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect. 

Your cache administrator is webmaster.
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a problem with your acl lists. Can you update us with any acl/allow lines you have?

It should look something like this:
Taken from: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl

```
How do I allow my clients to use the cache? Define an ACL that corresponds to your client's IP addresses. For example:

acl myclients src 172.16.5.0/24 
Next, allow those clients in the http_access list:

http_access allow myclients
```

Comment: I used webmin is there a way to do this quickly with webmin?

Comment: Sorry, never touched webmin. There has got to be a way to just view the full squid config file, probably either /etc/squid.conf or /etc/squid/squid.conf. I'd copy/paste the whole thing in here, making sure there is no sensitive information in it.